# Windows Phone 8 Cordova- Unable to open file from WWW folder

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, inappbrowser

I am using Cordova for Windows Phone 8 app, which has to load some local pages in InAppBrowser.
When we try loading remote urls like google or rediff its works perfectly fine, but when loading local files it shows error sayinh " we are having thouble displaying this page"

My code is 
 var link = "www/pages/windowsPayment.html";
 window.open(link, '_blank', 'location=yes');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it resolved....
user relative location url for HTML page. for example, if your page is in folder www/index and page you want to open is www/test.html open it with url ../test.html.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using navigatetolocalstreamuri?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/20/a-primer-on-webview-navigatetolocalstreamuri.aspx

Comment: its pure cordova app, I can not load HTML in some other native browser, as we have to listen response from browser